# Synchronizing multiple users in Blazor server

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

I have an almost-working server system for slow-paced multiplayer games like hangman, picture-find puzzles, etc. that require synchronization to work properly.  (everyone should be shown the picture at the same time, for example)

I want to use a Singleton game object to send out game start and update events to the multiple users, who are all on a page with that Singleton injected.

But my logic isn't right-- when a user leaves the game or loses connection, the stability of the page gets dodgy.  I do need to pick up the player if they reconnect, but of course the primary concern is that the page doesn't crash for all the users due to an orphaned event handler etc.

Can someone think of a nice clean architecture for doing this?  Almost everything I try works in dev and fails in practice with multiple users sharing a game especially on mobile devices.

Comment: I'm sorry,  but imho this is too broad and will attract opinion based answer, which are not suited for stack overflow, so I voted close. You might want to keep the game server separated from the clients and use SignalR.

Comment: Seems to me like a fairly simple "Blazor chat server" type thing, perhaps Blazor EventAgg would help; https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/blazor-eventaggregator-2-0-0-auto-refresh

Comment: I prefer to re-invent the wheel, as that's how I learn how things work.  I do like the comparison to a chat server, as I know there are about a dozen tutorials on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a game server that manages connected users and game rooms in their states. For example: create a TCP server (on C# console application perhaps), host it now let player A start a game of hangman. This creates an instance of `game room` on the server that has `players` `ended` `winner` etc. Now with this Id of the game room player A shares with B and they connect to the same game and now none of them is the host so the game doesn't end if the creator decided to leave, you can just wait for him to reconnect.

You can use services like `Playfab` to get a list of active servers. On your client application that will then connect to that TCP socket, send messages, and the server just forwards them all to other players. A simple pub-sub implementation in which clients "subscribe" to state changed event that reveals the next letter on the screen for both clients. A simple search on youtube can help you create a TCP connection and how to send messages between them.